# get input value using javascript and based on its value use javascript to insert a value elsewhere

Tags: javascript

I have this loading at the bottom of the page

```
if((document.getElementById('pcc').value)==="1") {
    var $postcontrr = "hello";
    document.write($postcontrr);
}
else {document.write ('this is messed up');}
```

in my form I have a field with `id=pcc` so the way I'm reading it is, if the value of field with id of pcc is 1 the the varialbe `$postcontrr` is going to be Hello and then the `document.write` should print Hello.  But I get nothing.  Not even the else statement prints.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make you javascript into a function so you can call it `onkeyup` of the input.  I would also change the inner html of an element instead of using `document.write` otherwise you will just be appending the text to the document each time the input changes.

```html
<script>
  function checkValue() {
    var $postcontrr;
    if (document.getElementById('pcc').value === "1") {
      $postcontrr = "hello";
    } else {
      $postcontrr = "this is messed up";
    }

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = $postcontrr;
  }
</script>
<input type="text" id="pcc" onkeyup="checkValue();">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: ok I'm on the right track thanks Pete.  I have got it to work once on the page but if I go and change the number in the field it doesn't update.  As stated in original question.  I have this function in my footer so its the last thing to load on the page.  Am I doing that right?

Comment: if you are using the function in the onkeyup as in my example above, then you need to include the function before the input is rendered (otherwise it will say that the function cannot be found).  You only put scripts at the end of the page if you are going to bind all your events after the page has loaded

Comment: Thanks.  Got it working but I think my issue is bigger than this.  I am trying to massage it so that I can get the input from 2 drop down selects (both being numbers) and depending on what numbers have been selected then have X displayed.  Im trying to convert a lookup table in excel into a form /mysql database format.  I think Im barking up the wrong tree somehow.

Comment: have a look at using `onchange` with the selects and then you can make an ajax call to the a page which will query the mysql db to return the results you need

Answer (score 1):

Get the expected result. No error here.
Please check it out in

```js
   if ((document.getElementById('pcc').value) === "1") {
     var $postcontrr = "hello";
     document.write($postcontrr);
   } else {
     document.write('this is messed up');
   }
```

```html
<html>
  <input id="pcc" value="1" type="text" />
</html>
```